# How can i disable caching in django-haystack?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack with drf-haystack for making a solr HaystackViewSet.
i need to paginate with just 20 items, and haystack fills all the num found results in one go. e.g. if 153 results are present, then haystack is making 8 queries. I want it to stop that and make just one query with one request. I am unable to find any settings in HAYSTACK which may disable the cache.

Question is: Is there a settings param or a class variable that i can set to disable caching altogether or atleast stop haystack for querying extra results.

params i specify other than the query, are: `start = 0, end = 20`

versions I am using -

- Django==3.2.3
- django-haystack==3.0
- djangorestframework==3.12.4
- drf-haystack==1.8.10
- pysolr==3.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this after stepping through code.

HAYSTACK_ITERATOR_LOAD_PER_QUERY = 20

Worked nicely for me.